# x86_64 Linux 3.0: Invalid Memory Addresses

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64

Processes on Linux 3.0 on x86_64 architecture have a 64-bit virtual address space.

It is clear that `0` is guaranteed to be an invalid memory address [see definition below] in this address space, as this is used to indicate a `NULL` pointer.

What other 64-bit numbers (if any) are guaranteed never to be valid memory addresses, and why?

For example, can `1` ever be a valid address? What about `2^64-1`?

**Definition**: What do you mean "*guaranteed to be an invalid memory address*" ?

```
void deref_and_assign(uint64_t i)
{
    char* p = (char*) i;
    *p = 42;
}
```

For the purposes of this question a guaranteed invalid memory reference means that the function `deref_and_assign` will always raise a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this information you're looking for? It's probably not information you should write code based upon. For research, of course, anything goes. ;)

Comment: Curiosity is good.  I am implementing a non-portable dynamic type (for a Linux/x86_64 target) and I am considering my options as far as overloading the lead 64-bit value "code unit".  One way to do it is to partition the code unit into (a) immediate values and (b) pointer to more info.  As a trivial example you could represent a dynamic number/string type as follows: (0-4095) it's a number represented immediately as the integers 0,1,2...4095; (4096-2^64) It's a pointer to a null-terminated string.  For a more real world example take a look at how rubys VALUE type works. ruby.h in ruby.tgz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On x86/64 if page translation enabled and the memory at virtual address 0 isn't accessible (because of the way physical memory is mapped into the virtual address space), 1 ... 4095 won't be accessible either because all these 4096 addresses correspond to a single page of memory and it can only be available or unavailable as a whole. It is a good idea to never map memory at virtual address 0. Not mapping it will help to catch many NULL pointer dereferences. The CPU here will generate a page fault (aka #PF) on unmapped locations or locations requiring higher privilege than the currently executing code.

In 64-bit mode the CPU may implement fewer (48+) than 64 virtual address bits and 64-bit addresses must contain either all zeroes or all ones in the bits that aren't implemented (the value, 0 or 1, must be the same as the value of the most significant implemented address bit, all of which can be interpreted as address sign-extension). Such addresses are called canonical. If you try to read or write memory using a non-canonical address, you'll get a general protection fault (AKA #GP).

So, depending on the OS (effectively, on its memory layout) and actual CPU you may come up with ranges of "invalid" memory addresses. If you try to read/write the kernel's memory from a user mode application, you'll get #PF. If you try to read/write unmapped memory (e.g. at address 0 through 4095), you'll get #PF. If you try to read/write at a non-canonical address, you'll get a #GP.

Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, 0..4095 is clear that the first page can't exist, thank you.  It is not clear about the 48 bit mode.  Can you give an example of a x86_64/Linux CPU that does that?  On my machine I see in /proc/*/maps that vsyscall is mapped to ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 for example, which is almost the top of vm.  Also: How can you "try" and read from kernel memory in userland?  All words used as memory addresses in userland dereference to vm.

Comment: ffffffffff600000 isn't necessarily the top. I've already mentioned that the top unimplemented bits are copies of the top implemented bit. So, if there're only 48 bits implemented, only the ffffff600000 part is "meaningful" and the rest, the top 16 bits (ffff) are just copies of the most significant "meaningful" bit, which is equal to 1.

Comment: You can use any address you like in both kernel and user mode. But the memory protection mechanisms won't let you actually read/write kernel memory from user mode code. Nothing prevents you from loading an arbitrary value (address) into, say, `rbx` and trying to execute `mov al, [rbx]` to read into `al` the value of the byte at the address contained in `rbx`. You can try. But the processor won't execute this instruction if there aren't sufficient privileges. Instead it will generate a #GP or #PF, which the OS will handle and the only meaningful action here would be to terminate the app.

Comment: How can I tell how many virtual address bits are implemented on my target platform (Linux 3.0 / x86_64) ?

Comment: I had a different understanding (perhaps incorrect) of kernel mode vs user mode as it relates to memory addressing.  I thought that when a process is in userland (outside of a syscall) any memory dereferenced (eg mov al, [rbx]) was treated as a virtual address in the processes virtual address space, and the page table was looked up by the CPU.  When the process enters a syscall it goes into kernel mode and then memory addresses are real physical addresses, but now that I write it down I think I'm wrong/confused.

Comment: I can't find the way to find out if it's 48 bits or more in the AMD manuals, but it seems that that is the current "limit", that's what the diagrams showing 64-bit virtual to physical address translation suggest. If the number can be queried, I'd expect `CPUID` or some MSR to be involved.

Comment: On the x86 CPU, page translation is effective in both kernel and user mode, you can't enable/disable it selectively. It's just that a portion of the kernel can have a 1-to-1 mapping if so is necessary or desired and the kernel portion of the virtual address space doesn't change when another processes is scheduled. Read the CPU manuals to get the actual picture of how the CPU works, it's all there.

Comment: I have open Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1 Chapter 3.3 Memory Organization.  Maybe something in here.

Answer (score 0):

You checked that a Linux process cannot [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with `MAP_FIXED` a segment starting at `(void*)0`.

So for practical purposes you can safely assume that the very first page `0 - 0xfff` is never `mmap`-ed (the 4Kb size of pages is processor and system dependent, but it is very often 4kb).  Then you can assume that dereferencing pointers (from inside a Linux application) inside this first page gives *SIGSEGV*

Likewise for the last page ending at  `0xffffffffffffffff` (ie 2^64-1)

Comment: mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) returns -1 and EPERM, so no you are wrong sorry.

Comment: Well, I believe I am even more right, because I did write that you can assume that the first page is not `mmap`-ed. I edited my answer.